# How to add style(css,js) to custom widget

Tags: magento2, custom, widget, styles

Hi i can try to add style to widget in the usual way.
like here https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-how-to-add-css-and-js-file-in-module/

its not working.

How can i add to css file to widget?

Comment: try to deploy your static content

Comment: i did it. its not helpd

Comment: I think you can't specifically add it on a widget but you can add it on a head block in frontend in general

Comment: share your code here

Answer (score 0):

Within your custom widget module create the following file:

```
view/frontend/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

Add the following code to _extend.less:

```
@import 'widget/example.less';
```

Create your .less file here:

```
view/frontend/web/css/source/widget/example.less
```